# Chrome Devtools not linking file with Hermes debugger

Tags: react-native, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, react-native-hermes

I recently enable Hermes engine on my mobile application but I've some issue when debugging using Chrome devtools.

I openned a workspace in the Devtools but some files are not liked to the debugger and I can't set breakpoint.

I can see that some file have a green dot in the icon (and then I can set breakpoint for these files)

but in my example, search.js is not linked.
FYI :

- my index.js only contains an export to search.js
- devtools are openned using chrome://inspect

[image: debugger linked file]

**index.js**

```
import Search from './search';

export default Search;
```

Is thers something I'm doing wrong?

thanks for your help

Comment: These files probably were inlined or excluded by the compiler.